# async Init and Property Changed in MvvmCross

Tags: mvvmcross

I have some async calls from Init in view model. The problem is that sometimes async call returns before OnCreate, and the property in UI is not updated.
Is there proper async/await model for this case, when we have to init async data?

pseudo code:

```
    // ViewModel
    public async Task Init(string id)
    {
        Url = await LoadUrlAsync(id);
    }


    // View
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ui_xml);
        ViewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModel_PropertyChanged;
    }

    void ViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _webView.LoadUrl(ViewModel.Url);
    }
```

Comment: Your code certainly looks like it should work. The first thing to check would be that the `Url` setter is in fact raising `PropertyChanged`. You may also find my [asynchronous initialization blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) helpful.

Comment: Since everything you have shown is synchronised on the UI thread, then the only way that the `async` call can return before `ViewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModel_PropertyChanged;` is called is if the `async` call executes synchronously - so you could just check for that in your `OnCreate` method - `if (ViewModel.Url `= null) ...`

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably do something like this in the `OnCreate` method, as you might want to add additional properties to it in the future.

```
private bool _loaded;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ui_xml);
    ViewModel.WeakSubscribe(() => ViewModel.Url, (s,e) => 
    {
        if (!_loaded)
            _webView.LoadUrl(ViewModel.Url);
    });

    if (ViewModel.Url != null) //Check if the async Init has finished already
    {
        _webView.LoadUrl(ViewModel.Url);
        _loaded = true;
    }
}
```