# Deferring PropertyChanged events until view bindings setup complete

Tags: mvvmcross

A number of our MVVMcross views depend remote services to fully display themselves. We typically kick this off a Task in ViewModel's Init() using to get it async. ViewModel properties are set in the Task upon completion, UI updated via PropertyChanged notifications.

Sometimes the remote data (and task) completes before the View has bound it's listeners and thus no property changed event is received.

This issue is touched on at [async Init and Property Changed in MvvmCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408287/async-init-and-property-changed-in-mvvmcross) but the solution feels like duplication of presentation logic.

We've had success buffering PropertyChanged notifications until the end of ViewDidLoad, but we'd like to turn below into a more generic solution by hooking into the MVX framework.

Is there a way to hook mvvmcross's view creation to fire our code off after viewDidLoad completes?

**Base View Model**

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : MvxViewModel{
        protected bool _deferPropertyChangedEvents = true;
        private readonly List<PropertyChangedEventArgs> _deferedPropertyChangedEvents = new List<PropertyChangedEventArgs>();

        public override void RaisePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs changedArgs)
        {
            lock(_deferedPropertyChangedEvents){
               if (!_deferPropertyChangedEvents)
               {
                  base.RaisePropertyChanged(changedArgs);
               }
               else
               {
                  // buffer it up
                  _deferedPropertyChangedEvents.Add(changedArgs);
               }
            }
        }

        public void EndDeferringPropertyChangedEvents()
        {
            lock(_deferedPropertyChangedEvents){    
              _deferPropertyChangedEvents = false;

              // playback all buffered notifications
              foreach (var e in _deferedPropertyChangedEvents)
              {
                  RaisePropertyChanged(e);
              }

              _deferedPropertyChangedEvents.Clear();
            }
        }
}
```

**Sample view**

```
public class SomeView : MvxViewController
    {
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            var bindings = this.CreateBindingSet<StopView, SomeViewModel>();
            .....
            bindings.Apply();

            // plays back any PropertyChanged() notifications that were buffered
            // up while the view was initializing
            // ---> want to find a way to have MVX call this
            ViewModel.EndDeferringPropertyChangedEvents();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple answer, I believe your own line can easily be called using a `BaseViewModel` cast:

```
        // ---> want to find a way to have MVX call this
        ((BaseViewModel)ViewModel).EndDeferringPropertyChangedEvents();
```

---

However, on a more technical note, I think it might be useful to further examine and understand why this `Deferring` code is necessary - to further take a look at what the underlying threading problems are.

There are a number of factors that are puzzling me at present::

1. During the line `bindings.Apply();` all **current** bound property values should be transferred from the `ViewModel` to the `View` - so calling `EndDeferringPropertyChangedEvents();` in the next line should (in theory) only rarely get different values.
2. Further, the default MvvmCross `RaisePropertyChanged` method changed notifications across to the UI thread. Because `ViewDidLoad` is also invoked on the UI thread, this means that any `RaisePropertyChanged` calls made on background threads during `ViewDidLoad` should all be automatically deferred until after `ViewDidLoad` has finished and the UI thread becomes available.
3. Looking at the `MvxNotifyPropertyChanged` code, the only potential gap I can see where mutli-threading might find a way through this automatic `RaisePropertyChanged` deferral is in this optimisation check:

   ```
           // check for subscription before potentially causing a cross-threaded call
           if (PropertyChanged == null)
               return;
   ```

   (from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxNotifyPropertyChanged.cs#L76)
4. If your ViewModel `Init` method is also using `async` for it's `Task` management, then this `async` code should also be using the UI thread - so the "callback" of this async operation should also be marshalled back to the UI thread (and so shouldn't be executed during `ViewDidLoad` itself).

As I said, these factors are puzzling me - I don't have a definitive answer/explanation - sorry! But I'd love to see an example problem and to try to help solve it at a generic level.

Comment: Your comments make me suspicious that the problem is being caused by something in our code - I'll dig around a bit more. Thanks for clarification on the binding process

Comment: Good luck. I'm still very much open to the idea this could be a general problem. Multithreading has ways of finding gaps in logic.

Comment: I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause, happens only say every one in 20 executions, and only on one screen. We'll use our workaround for now and try to find the cause later on.